# LinearFit with Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

How can apply Linear Fit with Google Earth Engine? I have the next code but I cannot see the values of the slope (scale) because are masked.

```js
var region = table

var start = '2000-01-01';
var end = '2014-12-31';


// This function adds a time band to the image.
var createTimeBand = function(image) {
  // Scale milliseconds by a large constant to avoid very small slopes
  // in the linear regression output.
  return image.addBands(image.metadata('system:time_start').divide(1e18));
};

// Load the input image collection: projected climate data.
var collection = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/MOD13Q1")
  .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1,1,'month'))
  .filterBounds(region)
  .map(createTimeBand)
  .filterDate(ee.Date('2000-01-01'), ee.Date('2014-12-31'))
  .map(function(image) {
    var date = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start'));
    var yearOffset = date.difference(ee.Date(start), 'year');
    var savi = image.expression(
      '(1 + L) * float(nir - red)/ (nir + red + L)',
      {
        'nir': image.select('sur_refl_b02'),
        'red': image.select('sur_refl_b01'),
        'L': 0.5
      });
    return ee.Image(1).addBands(yearOffset).addBands(savi).toDouble();
  });

Map.addLayer(collection)


print (collection)


// Reduce the collection with the linear fit reducer.
// Independent variable are followed by dependent variables.
var linearFit = collection.select(['constant', 'constant_2'])
  .reduce(ee.Reducer.linearFit());

Map.addLayer(linearFit)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were on the right track, but used an incorrect band name in the collection that you applied the linear fit reducer to. Here is a working version that renames the bands in the interest of readability.

```js
var start = ee.Date('2000-01-01');
var end = ee.Date('2014-12-31');

// This function adds a time band to the image.
var createTimeBand = function(image) {
  // Scale milliseconds by a large constant to avoid very small slopes
  // in the linear regression output.
  return image.addBands(image.metadata('system:time_start').subtract(start.millis()));
};

// Load the input image collection: projected climate data.
var collection = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/MOD13Q1")
  .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1,1,'month'))
  .map(createTimeBand)
  .filterDate(ee.Date('2000-01-01'), ee.Date('2014-12-31'))
  .map(function(image) {
    var date = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start'));
    var yearOffset = ee.Image(date.difference(ee.Date(start), 'year')).rename('year_offset');
    var savi = image.expression(
      '(1 + L) * float(nir - red)/ (nir + red + L)',
      {
        'nir': image.select('sur_refl_b02'),
        'red': image.select('sur_refl_b01'),
        'L': 0.5
      }).rename('savi');
    return ee.Image(1).addBands(yearOffset).addBands(savi).toDouble();
  });

Map.addLayer(collection, {}, 'collection', false);

// Reduce the collection with the linear fit reducer.
// Independent variable are followed by dependent variables.
var linearFit = collection.select(['year_offset', 'savi'])
  .reduce(ee.Reducer.linearFit());

Map.addLayer(
  linearFit.addBands(ee.Image(0).rename('dummy_band')),
  {bands:['scale', 'offset', 'dummy_band'], min:[0], max:[0.01,1,0]},
  'linearFit'
);
```

If you map the linear fit model's scale and offset to the red and green color channels, the result is rather interesting.

[image]

Comment: I am comparing the LinearFit from GEE with a Simple Linear Regression in Excel for some random points and are completely different.

I extract one pixel value from the result of the LinearFit in GEE and lets say that it is 0.012. Then, I plot a chart with SAVI collection and I extract (.csv) every single SAVI pixel value for each image (28 in total) and I do the LinearRegression in Excel and the result of the slope (scale) is completely different.

Comment: I do the same with the LinearRegression function from GEE and the result is exactly the same as with the LinearFit. I cannot understand why with GEE I get one result and with SPSS and EXCEL I get other results.